# iPad datetime input value format

Tags: forms, ipad, html, safari

I'm developing a webapp for iPad and i got stuck on something that should be pretty basic.
I have a form with a datetime input which can be edited but it's supposed to show a default value. I tried using the followin tag

```
<input type="datetime" id="xyz" name="xyz" value="1996-12-19T16:39:57" />
```

no default value shown, picker works fine, and if edited everything is fine, just not showing the default value I'm setting.
If I use this instead (which of course I can't use...) everything works perfectly and the default value is regularly shown

```
<input type="date" id="xyz" name="xyz" value="1996-12-19" />
```

I tried changing the date format in many ways, as suggested by various articles I found on the web, no luck...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a day search I found the solution while looking for something else (!!!)
Future reference for whoever gets stuck on this like me, the correct format on iOS for DATETIME input type is

yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ

and remember that it the date is GMT+0 (mine was off 2 hours)

hope it helps

Comment: For PHP echo date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z");